# Read gz file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gzip

I am trying to read/extract the contents of the file `train.gz`

my code:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('train.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

when i run:

```
print(file_content)
```

I get this error (on jupyter notebook):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2392/4036593255.py in <module>
----> 1 print(file_content)

MemoryError:
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

[MemoryError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.MemoryError) suggests that the file is too big for your runtime to process.

IIGC `train.gz` may be a training model and it may be that you must deal with this model as a single chunk. If so, your best solution is to find a bigger (more memory) machine.

If at all possible (and strongly preferred), you should stream the uncompressed file through your program so that you may constrain the buffer|in-memory window onto it thereby limiting the possibility that you'll run out of memory.

Comment: This is a Google Cloud Jupyter Notebook instance : n1-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 15 GB RAM)

Is there a way of knowing if thats enough

Comment: for example, should i focus on RAM and upgrade upwards

See machine options below:

https://prnt.sc/25v2943

Comment: Ok, after upgrading to a higher Machine (RAM = 30Gb) I dont get the error anymore, however when i ```print(file_content)``` then I get this error

```The kernel for Untitled.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

```

Is it necessary to print file or reading this as a dataframe may be sufficient